# Is having hard-coded API keys such as the SafetyNet API key considered a vulnerability?

Tags: android, api, exposure, information-exposure, hardcoded

I have a scenario where the developers are using SafetyNet API to protect their Android apps. I observed that the SafetyNet API key has been hard-coded within the apk file. This is the first time I came across this behaviour.

Is this exposure of API key is considered a vulnerability?

Because exposure of Google Maps API Keys are generally not considered vulnerable.

NOTE: SafetyNet API is deprecated which is a different problem :)

Comment: Where would you put the API key instead?

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard implementation of SafetyNet API attestation. It is recommended to put SafetyNet API key in `strings.xml`. The key is required to make attestation call to SafetyNet client in the Google Play Services app. The key usage is bound to the package name and SHA-1 certificate fingerprint of the apps declared in Google developer account. So, undeclared apps cannot use that key for their own attestation to get around API rate limits. You can verify if that is the case by using that key in your test app. If you receive an error response, that means the key is not reusable by undeclared parties or else let the owner know that someone can deplete their 10,000 requests per day rate limit of the API.